# Does Normalized Estimation Error Squared (NEES) and Normalized Innovation Error Squared (NIS) Only Apply to Kalman Filtering?

Tags: gaussian-process, estimators, kalman-filter, consistency

Regarding the NEES and NIS metrics, do they only apply to Kalman Filtering? Or can I use them for any estimator that outputs a prediction and has a covariance matrix? I have never seen NEES applied to any other model, but I want to use it for proving consistency for a Gaussian Process Regression Model.

Using the equations for NEES and NIS from the paper [Weak in the NEES?: Auto-tuning Kalman Filters with Bayesian Optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.08855.pdf).

NEES:
$$
\epsilon_{x,k} = e_{x,k}^{\top}P_{k,k}^{-1}e_{x,k}
$$
NIS:
$$
\epsilon_{z,k} = e_{z,k}^{\top}S_{k,k}^{-1}e_{z,k}
$$
where $P$ is the covariance matrix and $S$ is the innovation covariance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have the equation, you can use them wherever you like. An intuitive explanation of this metrics is that it gives a lot of importance to errors when the filter was pretty confident of its estimation (little covariance) while having a big error but being quite uncertain will not impact much the NEES score.

Therefore, you can use it as a metric for anything you like, as long as it's relevant.